# How to make one widget disappear when another widget is clicked?

Tags: flutter

My page has two stateful widgets (say A and B). When A is clicked, I want to B to disappear and then A to occupy the full width of the screen. I cannot figure out how to make B disappear.

A is expanded as expected but the presence of B is causing an overflow. I tried using ValueListenableBuilder to pass a variable which will then trigger the visibility of B to become false but couldn't implement it.

````
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter layout demo',
        home: Scaffold(
            return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[HeadCardApp("Society", 'assets/houses.png', 1), //Widget A
                  HeadCardApp("Community",'assets/discuss.png', 2)], //Widget B
              ),
            ),
          );}
  }
}
class HeadCardApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final String heading;
  final String imgLink;
  final int stateNo;
  HeadCardApp(this.heading, this.imgLink, this.stateNo);
  @override
  HeadCard createState() => HeadCard(heading, imgLink, stateNo);
}
class HeadCard extends State<HeadCardApp> {
  String heading;
  String imgLink;
  double _width = 380;
  double _height = 180;
  int stateNo;
  HeadCard(this.heading, this.imgLink, this.stateNo);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        if(stateNo == 1){
 //Space to make changes
        }
        else
          {

          }
        setState(() {
            _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
            _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        });
      },
    child: AnimatedContainer(
      width: _width,
      height: _height,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,


      ),
    ));
  }
}```
````

Comment: You can wrap your widget with https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. How to trigger visibility of one widget when another one is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

you can put the Column part of the MaterialApp inside a StatfulWidget an like that you can change the visibility by calling setState in the new StatfulWiget to change view visibility.